# atualizar aba da tabcontrol

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou criando um programa em Windows Forms e na minha página coloquei um *Tab Control* com uma aba para cadastrar e inserir os dados no MySQL e a outra para ver os dados cadastrados em uma ComboBox.

Só que quando insiro um dado pela aba de cadastro e mudo para a outra, o meu ComboBox não tem os dados inseridos, ai eu tenho que fechar o programa e abrir novamente para aparecer na ComboBox.

Como faço para quando inserir em uma aba ele reconhecer na outra?

Comment: A resposta atende o que foi pedido? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este é exatamente o comportamento esperado. Uma vez carregado o `ComboBox`, você vai precisar carregar os dados para ele novamente quando fizeres novas inserções.

Tem diversas formas de se tratar isso: pode atualizar ao adicionar um item, pode atualizar quando trocar de aba e por aí vai.

Eu aconselho a recarregar a combo sempre que o usuário trocar da primeira aba para a segunda.

Para isso, é necessário usar o evento [`Selecting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selecting(v=vs.110).aspx) do `TabControl`. Obs.: Não esqueça de inscrever o evento no componente.

O código seria mais ou menos isso

```
void tabControl_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
     TabPage tabPageSelecionada = (sender as TabControl).SelectedTab;

     //troque tabPageConsulta pelo "Name" previamente definido para a tab page
     if(tabPageSelecionada == tabPageConsulta)  
     {
         //Buscar os dados no banco e recarregar a combobox
     }
}
```